# Send email body contain data in table format

Tags: spring, email, notifications

I have a use case where email body should contain data in tablular format.
Let's say I have a student model containing fields id, name, list of marks subject wise. I actually want to send email to each individual student with their marks pers subject wise in tabular format.

Please let me know your input on this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Emails body can contain HTML and support `text/html` MIME type. With it, you can create a more elaborate presentation than with plain text, by directly creating a [table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table) for example.

Something like this should do the trick :

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Your Marks</title>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
   </head>
   <body>
      <table>
          <thead>
             <th>Subject</th>
             <th>Mark</th>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
              ...... your content here                
          </tbody> 
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

The Spring Framework has pretty good integration with the template engine [Thymeleaf](https://www.thymeleaf.org/index.html). Using it would simplify the creation of the body.

[Sending Email in Spring with Thymeleaf](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springmail.html)

Comment: Thnks for your quick response, let me try this one.